# Get attachment ID of author_meta image - Attachment Metadata

Tags: images, uploads, attachments, author, profiles

I've created a custom field in user profile where upload a profile image. It's very simple.

To create fields I've used:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'cover_image_function' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'cover_image_function' );
function cover_image_function( $user ) 
{
   <h3>Cover Image</h3>
    <style type="text/css">
    .fh-profile-upload-options th,
    .fh-profile-upload-options td,
    .fh-profile-upload-options input {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .user-preview-image {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        width: 300px;
    }
    </style>
    <table class="form-table fh-profile-upload-options">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="image">Cover Image</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <img class="user-preview-image" src="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'mycoverimage', $user->ID ) ); ?>">
                <input type="text" name="mycoverimage" id="mycoverimage" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'mycoverimage', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" />
                <input type='button' class="button-primary" value="Upload Image" id="coverimage"/><br />
                <span class="description">Please upload your cover image.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function( $ ) {
        $( 'input#coverimage' ).on('click', function() {
            tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true');

            window.send_to_editor = function( html ) 
            {
                imgurl = $( 'img', html ).attr( 'src' );
                $( '#mycoverimage' ).val(imgurl);
                tb_remove();
            }

            return false;
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
}
```

To save my image:

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_cover_image' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_cover_image' );
function save_cover_image( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'mycoverimage', $_POST[ 'mycoverimage' ] );
}
```

Everything works fine but I can't retrieve the `attachment ID` for generating the **thumbnails and smaller sizes**. For now I can just get the url like:

```
echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'mycoverimage', $user->ID ) );
```

I've even used the known method like in other questions:

```
function get_attachment_id($image_url) {
    global $wpdb;
    $attachment = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url )); 
    return $attachment[0]; 
}
```

But It doesn't work. Is it possible that the image doesn't generate any attachment metadata, while uploading? And how Can I do it? Even suggestions, articles or questions already answered would be appreciated. Everything but a plugin, I want build a custom code. Thanks!

Comment: How does your form actually handle the image? What does $_POST[ 'mycoverimage' ] contain?

Comment: Thanks @AndyMacaulay-Brook, I edit the question and insert the function details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally solved! The problem was that simply using

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'mycoverimage', $_POST[ 'mycoverimage' ] );
```

The image was saved without generating attachment metadata. In fact, checking my table, it got only `usermeta id` which is not the attachment id. So I had to change a bit my uploading function according to [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) with the use of `wp_insert_attachment` like:

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_cover_image' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_cover_image' );
function save_cover_image( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    {
        return false;
    }
    $filename = $_POST['mycoverimage'];
    $parent_post_id = 0;
    $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $attachment = array(
        'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
        'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
        'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
        'post_author'    => $uid
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'mycoverimage', $_POST[ 'mycoverimage' ] );
}
```

At this point I have a `usermeta id` and an `attachment id` which I can easily retrieve for thumbs and other operations. Thanks to @majick anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use the more newer media manager dialog; WordPress will hanlde all the image upload stuff, including generating intermediate sizes and attachement metadata.

Here a working example (it is a quick example built from a previous code, it may needs some tweaks to be used on production):

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_wp_media_files' );
function load_wp_media_files( $page ) {
  if( $page == 'profile.php' || $page == 'user-edit.php' ) {
    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugins_url( '/js/myscript.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '0.1' );
  }
}

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'cover_image_function' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'cover_image_function' );
function cover_image_function( $user ) 
{
    $image_id = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'mycoverimage', true );
    if( intval( $image_id ) > 0 ) {
        // Change with the image size you want to use
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'medium', false, array( 'id' => 'user-preview-image' ) );
    } else {
        $image = '<img id="user-preview-image" src="https://some.default.image.jpg" />';
    }
    ?>
   <h3>Cover Image</h3>
   <style type="text/css">
    .fh-profile-upload-options th,
    .fh-profile-upload-options td,
    .fh-profile-upload-options input {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .user-preview-image {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        width: 300px;
    }
    </style>
    <table class="form-table fh-profile-upload-options">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="image">Cover Image</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <?php echo $image; ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="mycoverimage" id="mycoverimage" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'mycoverimage', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" />
                <input type='button' class="button-primary" value="Upload Image" id="coverimage"/><br />
                <span class="description">Please upload your cover image.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_cover_image' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_cover_image' );
function save_cover_image( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'mycoverimage', $_POST[ 'mycoverimage' ] );
}  


// Ajax action to refresh the user image
add_action( 'wp_ajax_cyb_get_image_url', 'cyb_get_image_url'   );
function cyb_get_image_url() {
    if(isset($_GET['id']) ){
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image( filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT ), 'medium', false, array( 'id' => 'user-preview-image' ) );
        $data = array(
            'image'    => $image,
        );
        wp_send_json_success( $data );
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }
}
```

And myscript.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

      jQuery('input#coverimage').click(function(e) {

             e.preventDefault();
             var image_frame;
             if(image_frame){
                 image_frame.open();
             }
             image_frame = wp.media({
                           title: 'Select Media',
                           multiple : false,
                           library : {
                                type : 'image',
                            }
                       });

                       image_frame.on('close',function() {
                          // get selections and save to hidden input plus other AJAX stuff etc.
                          var selection =  image_frame.state().get('selection');
                          var gallery_ids = new Array();
                          var my_index = 0;
                          selection.each(function(attachment) {
                             gallery_ids[my_index] = attachment['id'];
                             my_index++;
                          });
                          var ids = gallery_ids.join(",");
                          jQuery('input#mycoverimage').val(ids);
                          Refresh_Image(ids);
                       });

                      image_frame.on('open',function() {
                        var selection =  image_frame.state().get('selection');
                        ids = jQuery('input#mycoverimage').val().split(',');
                        ids.forEach(function(id) {
                          attachment = wp.media.attachment(id);
                          attachment.fetch();
                          selection.add( attachment ? [ attachment ] : [] );
                        });

                      });

                    image_frame.on('toolbar:create:select',function() {

                        image_frame.state().set('filterable', 'uploaded');

                    });

                    image_frame.open();
     });

});

function Refresh_Image(the_id){
        var data = {
            action: 'cyb_get_image_url',
            id: the_id
        };

        jQuery.get(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

            if(response.success === true) {
                jQuery('#user-preview-image').replaceWith( response.data.image );
            }
        });
}
```

Note that **this code stores image id on user meta field** instead of full size image url as you was doing before, so you can get any image size form the user meta field:

```
$image_id = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'mycoverimage', true );
$fulle_user_image = wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'full' );
```

Comment: Yes, try it out. You will be using WordPress media manager to manage the image field. Let me know if you have some problems understanding what the code does.

Comment: Years later I would use no JQuery, and at least typed php. Wordpress looks quite weird after working for years on Symfony.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it will make a difference, but as you just want one value you can get `get_var` instead of `get_col`. I tweaked the query slightly to what I know works:

```
function get_attachment_id($image_url) {
    global $wpdb;
    $attachment = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."posts WHERE post_type='attachment' AND guid='%s'", $image_url )); 
    return $attachment; 
}
```

And making use you are not doing `esc_attr` on the URL value before sending it to the function or it won't match to it.

**EDIT** You could try this to (less strictly) just match the URL path to the `guid` instead of the full URL:

```
function get_attachment_id($image_url) {
    $parseurl = parse_url($image_url);
    $path = $parseurl['path'];

    global $wpdb;
    $attachments = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID,guid FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."posts WHERE post_type='attachment'");
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        if (strstr($attachment->guid,$path)) {return $attachment->ID;}
    }
    echo "<!-- All Attachments "; print_r($attachments); echo "-->"; // debug output
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your precious answer! Unfortunately echoing `get_attachment_id($image_url)` even with your changes doesn't give back any value. I'm desperate...

Comment: added an alternative, not be the most efficient way but it may work for you in the short term.

Comment: Thanks dude, I've solved! The attachment wasn't an attachment actually. I've just used wp_insert_attachment in my uploading function. Thanks anyway. Have a great day!

Comment: no problemo, yep that would do it. have a great one yourself. :-)